# wait_event_interruptible and signal_pending

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

I've been reading LDD3 book and I've stumbled upon the following piece of code:

```
int somefunc()
{
   [...]

    wait_event_interruptible(data->wait, !data->loops);
    if (signal_pending(current))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
}
```

However, in some other parts of this book, the authors used a little bit different approach to (at least for me) do the same thing.

```
int someOtherFunc()
{
   [...]

    if (wait_event_interruptible(data->wait, !data->loops)) {
      return -ERESTARTSYS;
   }
}
```

Is there any difference between these two? Or perhaps it's just a matter of style?

From what I understand the non-negative return code from wait_event_interruptible indicates that the call was interrupted by some source of signal, so it kinda looks the same as what the call to signal_pending checks. Am I right?

Comment: One difference is that the first piece of code will always checks for pending signals, and the second piece of code only will only check for pending signals if the condition is initially false.

Comment: Of course, a function with return type `void` (as in the two snippets) cannot return a value. :-)

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice. It's obviously a pseudo-code. I've copied the function's body from the driver's code and just added a declaration to show that the code belongs to the function. I will fix it as it may be confusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both code snippets wait on a waitqueue and return `-ERESTARTSYS` if the wait gets interrupted by a signal. The call to `signal_pending()` after `wait_event_interruptible()` could be avoided, because the latter already returns `-ERESTARTSYS` in case of interruption by signal (see [the docstring comment on its definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.3/source/include/linux/wait.h#L482)). The second code snippet seems like a cleaner way to implement the logic.

You should check the rest of the code to see if there is an outstanding reason to call `signal_pending()` explicitly. The first function may want to return early regardless of the result of `wait_event_interruptible()` if there is a signal to be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

`wait_event_interruptible()` will return 0 without sleeping if the condition is initially true. The first code snippet always checks for pending signals. The second code snippet only checks for pending signals if it actually needed to wait for the condition to become true.